# Does react native support repeating-linear-gradient?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to have a repeating-linear-gradient for my view in React Native. However i couldn't find any information or library that would help me use it.
I found a library named react-native-linear-gradient but it seems to be helpful to only have simple linear gradient.
Thanks for your help in advance

CSS

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  -55deg,
  #222,
  #222 10px,
  #333 10px,
  #333 20px
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, styles are specified with an object wherein the key is the camelCase version of the style name, and the value is the style’s value. If the value is not explicitly typeof 'number', the entire value must be a single string. Within that string, normal css style names can be used.

Here is an example:

```
<ExampleComponent
  style={{
    background: 'repeating-linear-gradient(-55deg, #222, #222 10px,#333 10px, #333 20px)',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
  }}
/>
```

Comment: The question is referring to repeating-linear-gradient support in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

As far as August 2023 the answer is no, neither React-Native nor [React-Native-Linear-Gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/380) support repeating-linear-gradient.

Answer (score -2):

I have used react-native-linear-gradient for my splash screen

fist I have set 4 different colors and make it a gradient with white color.

```
const gradient1 = [Colors.secondary1Color, Colors.white];
const gradient2 = [Colors.primary1Color, Colors.white];
const gradient3 = [Colors.secondaryColor, Colors.white];
const gradient4 = [Colors.primaryColor, Colors.white];
```

I first set `this.state = {changeGradient: true}`

then I have this `changeGradient` function which changes the const gradient colors ever had a second

```
changeGradient = async () => {
        console.log("changeGradient", await this.state.gradient);
        if (this.state.changeGradient) {
            setTimeout(async () => {
                await this.setState(({ gradient }) => ({ gradient: gradient === gradient1 ? gradient2 : gradient === gradient2 ? gradient3 : gradient === gradient3 ? gradient4 : gradient1 }));
                this.changeGradient();
            }, 500);
        }
    };
```

Then, I render in the `Lineargradient` component

```
<LinearGradient colors={this.state.gradient} style={styles.container}>
</LinearGradient >
```

You're good to go!!!
Hope this helps you!

Comment: This answer seems to provide a way to change the gradient color in a loop, rather then to replicate the styling of `repeating-linear-gradient` in CSS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient